# No error's contained but still can't execute code

Tags: java

My code has no errors, but I can't seem to execute it through Eclipse. I've tried including `static void` but that hasn't worked for me either. Any ideas?

```
package CarWasher;

public class CarWasherQueues {
    


    public static void main(String[] args){
        
    }
    
    int intArray[] = null;
    int rear = -1;
    int itemCount = 0;
    int front = 0;  int peek() {
        
        return intArray[front];
        
    }
    
    Boolean isEmpty() {
        return itemCount == 0;
    }
    Boolean isFull() {
        return itemCount == 5;
    }
    
    int size() {
        return itemCount;
    }
    
    void insert(int data) {
        
        if (!isFull()) {
            intArray[++rear] = data;
            itemCount++;
        }
    }
    
    int removeData() {
        int data = intArray[front++];
        
        if(front == 5) {
            front = 0;
        }
        
        itemCount--;
        return data;
        
        }
    
    void main() {
        /*Insert 5 Items */
        insert(3);
        insert(5);
        insert(9);
        insert(1);
        insert(12);
        
        // front : 0
        // rear  : 4
        // index : 0 1 2 3 4
        // queue : 3 5 9 1 12
        insert(15);
        
        // front : 0 
        // rear  : 5
        // index : 0 1 2 3 4 5
        // queue : 16 5 9 1 12 15
        
        // As queue is full elements will not be inserted 
        insert(17);
        insert(18);
        
        // index : 0 1 2 3 4 5
        // queue : 16 5 9 1 12 15
        
        System.out.println("Element at front: %d\n" +  peek());
        
        System.out.println("-----------------------------\n");
        System.out.println("index : 5 4 3 2 1 0\n");
        
        while(!isEmpty()) {
            int n = removeData();
            System.out.println("%d " + n);
            
        }
        
    
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: When you said "I can't seem to execute it through Eclipse," do you mean it does nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main method must have the expected signature (see [the language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4)). Use either

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

or

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

(Where the variable name `args` does not matter, but everything else does.)

Comment: @LeeMeally  Your code does run, it just doesn't do anything. The main method you added is empty. Move the code from your old `void main()` into the `public static void main(String[] args){`.